# Angular Material: How to change the background color for the mat spinner path

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, spinner

I created a mat progress spinner, changed the color of the stroke, but need to know how to change the CSS for the remaining stroke path

I tried changing the color but it changed the stroke color. But I could not find anything related to path CSS. I could see circle is only getting generated when we use mat-progress-spinner

```
<mat-progress-spinner [color]="'orange'" [mode]="'determinate'" 
[diameter]="80" strokeWidth="5" [value]=" 70">
</mat-progress-spinner>
```

```
.mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: green;
}

.mat-progress-spinner path, .mat-spinner path {
    stroke: red;
}
```

for example, value is 70 in the above example, then for 70 it should be mapped with orange color, need help on how to show different color for the remaining 30 value

- 70 - orange color
- 30 - yellow color (**need solution for this**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle is created dynamically, so you wouldn't find a property to color the remaining portion (since that remaining portion is not painted at all - there is nothing there that we can change the color of);

But you can get the effect that you're looking for... you can do this by:

- creating an image of the complete circle, placing it in your `mat-card`... I took the following purple image

[image]

- Next, placing the `mat-spinner` on top of this static image via `position:absolute`

relevant **HTML**:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <h2 class="example-h2">Result</h2>

        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNUGr.png' alt='background'/>

        <mat-progress-spinner class="example-margin" [color]="color" [mode]="mode" [value]="value">
        </mat-progress-spinner>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

relevant **CSS**:

```
mat-progress-spinner{    
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  left: 19px;
}

circle{
  stroke-width: 11%;
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bokkjt)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks good. But if the size of the spinner changes means then i need to increase the size of the background image also. It might be somewhat two way work for me.

Comment: for the exact results, best to keep the size fixed... else manipulate the size of the complete circle via `transform: scale(1.1);` property